# regex, image src may have many different paths and I want to replace with a specific path

Tags: regex, replace

So I have a database from a wordpress multisite.  I'm doing a search and replace on a table with regex and need to make all src's of a specific image name (image2.jpg) point to a single directory.  Here's an example.  I may have:

```
src="http://domain.com/path/weird/different/image2.jpg
```

and

```
src="http://domain2.com/path2/differentpath/helloworld/image2.jpg
```

I need to replace everything between `src="` and `/image.jpg with a specific domain/filepath`.

I'm not great with regex stuff, I try, but it's just not my strong suit.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Search:** `src="[^"]*image2\.jpg`

**Replace:** `src="http://mydomain.com/mypath/image2.jpg`

The `[^"]*` eats up any characters that are not a double quote.

In the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yR5fL2), see the substitutions pane at the bottom.

**In PHP (should work with WordPress):**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/src="[^"]*image2\.jpg/', 
                 'src="http://mydomain.com/mypath/image2.jpg',
                 $str);
```

Comment: thank you, going to try this, I'm doing it in a mysql query from centos command line.  I recently installed the preg_replace system for mysql

Comment: haven't tested yet, been busy and this client has been quite, will be testing this week.

Comment: FYI, added a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yR5fL2) (see the substitutions at the bottom)

Comment: @ChrisFlannagan Actually since zx81 added a regex demo too, why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
/(?<=src=")(.*?)(?=\Q/image2.jpg\E)/
```

This matches anything that goes in between "`src="`" and "`/image2.jpg`", so you are free to replace this with your specific `domain/filepath`.

Depending on your language/ tool, you may have to escape the leading `/` in `/image2.jpg`.

```
  > Positive Lookbehind - assert that match must be following 'src="'
  |
  |  Anything    > Positive Lookahead - assert that match
  |         |    | is before '/image2.jpg' literally.
/(?<=src=")(.*?)(?=\Q/image2.jpg\E)/
```

Also try out an [online regex tester](http://regex101.com/r/jG3bP2).